# Como recuperar dados de Input para o CodeBehind ASP.net

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: eu tenho o meu codigo HTML e estou fazendo a validação dos campos com JavaScript, mas gostaria de chamar a função e passar o valor no CodeBehind. Exemplo String nome = uname(meu input);

É possível ?

```
 <!--Form de Login -->
    <label><b>Usuario</b></label>
    <input type="text" runat="server" placeholder="Nome de Usuario" name="uname" id ="uname" onkeydown ="return soLetra();" onkeyup="return AutoTabular(40, uname, psw);" onkeypress ="return LimiteMaximoTextArea(uname, 15)" onclick ="return AlterarCampo(uname);"/>

    <label><b>Senha</b></label>
    <input type="password" runat="server" placeholder="Senha" name="psw" id ="psw" onkeypress="return LimiteMaximoTextArea(psw, 8);"/>

    <button type="submit" runat="server"  onclick ="teste2()">Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está usando **Web Forms**, o apropriado seria usar os controles do próprio `asp.net` (`<asp:TextBox>`).

Considerando que a validação esteja sendo feita com `javascript` você poderia fazer o seguinde:

- Executar a sua validação `javascript` em uma função que retornará um `bool`
- Se for retornado `true`, sua será feito o `PostBack`

No exemplo a seguir, `ValidarForm()` seria a sua função `javascript`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEntrar" Text="Entrar" OnClientClick="return ValidarForm();" OnClick="btnEntrar_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" />
```

*Obs.: O ideal realmente é que você utilize os **web controls** do `asp.net` para que seja possível acessar os dados pelo code behind*